Konva@9.3.9 + Animation，The page crashes after running for a while
Environment:
Window System
Chrome Browser
Problem Description:
Run time: After running for about an hour, the page crashes ，I guess it may be because the added Text node has too many attributes. This problem has been bothering me for a long time. How to solve this?Thanks a lot for help.
reproduce code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9.3.9/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Konva Animation Stress Test Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    function update(layer, frame) {
      var angularSpeed = 100;
      var angularDiff = (angularSpeed * frame.timeDiff) / 1000;
      var shapes = layer.getChildren();

      for (var n = 0; n < shapes.length; n++) {
        var shape = shapes[n];
        shape.rotate(angularDiff);
      }
    }
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    layer.listening(false);

    var colors = [
      'red',
      'orange',
      'yellow',
      'green',
      'blue',
      'cyan',
      'purple'
    ];
    var colorIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      var color = colors[colorIndex++];
      if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
      }

      var randWidth = Math.random() * 100 + 20;
      var randHeight = Math.random() * 100 + 20;
      var randX = Math.random() * stage.width() - 20;
      var randY = Math.random() * stage.height() - 20;

      var box = new Konva.Text({
        x: randX,
        y: randY,
        label: "文字",
        type: "Text",
        lineHeight: 1.2,
        fontFamily: "微软雅黑",
        letterSpacing: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        fontSize: 40,
        text: "污水处理系统",
        stroke: "#000000",
        strokeWidth: 0,
        strokeStyle: "solid",
        isLock: false,
        isView: true,
        fill: "#0d457dff",
        align: "center",
        textDecoration: "normal",
        fontStyle: "bold",
        verticalAlign: "middle",
        shadowColor: "#000000",
        shadowBlur: 0,
        shadowOffsetX: 1,
        shadowOffsetY: 1,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        dataSource: "",
        dataSourceUnit: "",
        borderOpen: false,
        shadowOpen: false,
        dataSourceFilterText: "+ 添加过滤器",
        dataSourceFilterApply: false,
        dataSourceFilterRes: "",
        filters: [],
        wrap: "char",
        isNeedUpdateDataSource: true,
        maxLevel: 2,
        multipleSelect: false,
        comType: "Text",
        name: "6a6abb7e-6c16-4598-a533-575f7b211c33",
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        skewX: 0,
        skewY: 0,
      });

      layer.add(box);
    }

    stage.add(layer);

    var anim = new Konva.Animation(function (frame) {
      update(layer, frame);
    }, layer);

    anim.start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>

The page can run for a long time without crashing.

Please edit your question to include your system specifications, and what browser you are using, version, etc
